# Apache nested virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, mod-proxy

I have two virtual hosts in a apache server and I would like to do something but I don't know if is possible.

The thing is that I have the main application developed and ruby and the blog is in wordpress. So right now I have something like this:

- example.com and blog.example.com

What I would like to do is that all the request to www.example.com/blog are served by the blog.example.com, but without doing a redirects (i.e I don't want the user to see a change in the URL)

What I've tried so far is to do a proxy in the VirtualHost:

```
<Location  /blog>
    ProxyPassReverse http://blog.example.com
    ProxyPassReverse http://blog.example.com:80
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule blog/(.*)$ http://blog.example.com/$1 [QSA,P,L]
</Location>
```

And it works, but once I'm in the other app all the links are inside blog.example.com and not in example.com/blog.

Do you know a workaround for this?

Thanks in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Links are handled in your content, not by Apache.  `ProxyPassReverse` only translates for redirects - everything else is on you.

Fix it by using host-relative paths in your content - instead of linking to `http://blog.example.com/dir/page.html`, link to `/dir/page.html`.

If the links are being dynamically generated by WordPress, then it's probably reading the host header; `ProxyPreserveHost` would be the normal way around this, but won't work with both vhosts being on the same listener - you'd end up feeding requests right back to the vhost that's doing the proxying.

Answer (score 0):

For a reverse proxy, fixing the links in your content output (as mentioned in the other answer) is the better way to go, however [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) is another possibility.

That said, if you're serving both applications out of the same Apache server why bother with the two virtual hosts? You should be able to serve two different languages from the same virtual host, that way you can skip the reverse proxy step completely.

Comment: Oh ok! thanks, Could you tell me where to read to learn how to serve two applications with differents languages in the same virtual host?

Comment: Pretty much the same way you do it for one. Just use `<Location>` and `<Directory>` as necessary to isolate the settings for each and use your rewrite rules to route the request to the correct app entry points.